# Jquery add a blank line on a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select element populated with Ajax using jquery like this:

Javascript:

```
oCssSet = document.getElementById("sel_opt");    

$.each(data, function (index) {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value = data[index].selID;
            opt.innerHTML = data[index].selDescr;

            oCssSet.appendChild(opt);

        });
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" onChange="AddOptions(this);" id="sel_opt" disabled></select>
```

All done, but when there is just one value and i click on it my function does not start, i need to have ever at the top of my select a blank line, how is possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just add `<option>Please select...</option>` to the HTML

Comment: yes, if it's just one value, "onchange" is not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it statically to your html:

```html
<select class="form-control" onChange="AddOptions(this);" id="sel_opt" disabled>
<option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one, make it a checkbox :)

```js
function AddOptions() {
  var val = this.value;
  if (this.type=="checkbox" && !this.checked) val="";
  console.log(val);
  
}
var data = [{
  selId: "option1",
  selDesc: "Option 1"
}]
/*
,{
  selId: "option2",
  selDesc: "Option 2"
}*/

$(function() {
  if (data.length == 1) {
    var html = "<label>" + data[0].selDesc +
      "<input type='checkbox' value='" + data[0].selId + "' id='sel_opt' /></label>";
    $("#sel_opt").replaceWith(html)
  } else {
    $.each(data, function(_, item) {
      var $opt = $("<option/>", {
        value: item.selId,
        text: item.selDesc
      });
      $("#sel_opt").append($opt);
    });
  }
  $("#sel_opt").on("change",AddOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="sel_opt">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
</select>
```